# @WebService not getting called after springboot upgrade 3.1.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, web-services, soap

Migrated from springboot 2.7.10 to 3.1.0
The webservice calls stopped working,

```
import jakarta.jws.WebService;

import au.com.mydump.offers.wsdl.ErrorInfo;
import au.com.mydump.offers.wsdl.ErrorSeverity;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.NotImplementedException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.mydump.esb.offer.service.PublishOfferService;
import com.mydump.offers.wsdl.Fault;
import com.mydump.offers.wsdl.Offer;
import com.mydump.offers.wsdl.OffernotifyrequestType;
import com.mydump.offers.wsdl.OffernotifyresponseType;
import com.mydump.offers.wsdl.PublishofferrequestType;
import com.mydump.offers.wsdl.PublishofferresponseType;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;

@Endpoint
@WebService(endpointInterface = "au.com.mydump.offers.wsdl.Offer", serviceName = "OfferService", portName = "OfferServicePort")
@Slf4j
public class OfferEndpoint implements Offer {

    @Autowired
    private PublishOfferService service;

    @Override
    public PublishofferresponseType publishOffer(PublishofferrequestType parameters) throws Fault {
        try {
            log.info("OfferEndpoint : publishOffer()");
            return service.publishOffer(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            ErrorInfo errorInfo = new ErrorInfo();
            errorInfo.setSeverity(ErrorSeverity.ERROR);
            errorInfo.setErrorID("1");
            throw new Fault(e.getMessage(), errorInfo);
        }
    }

}
```

Below are the related libraries from my build.gradle:

implementation 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:4.0.5'

implementation 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:4.0.5'

implementation 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:4.0.2'

jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:4.0.1'

jaxws files("${projectDir}/src/main/java")

It's not printing the log that I added in my class OfferEndpoint, means its not entering it at all. It works fine in spingboot 2.7.x.
I tried to look at the @Endpoint, @Webservice annotations, none of them are deprecated. Why would it stopped working? Can someone please help.